# Events do not work with the elements which are dropped - UI droppable

Tags: jquery, user-interface

I want to display a properties div on click event of another div named **abc**, which has been dropped using jquery UI droppable. I could show the properties  div by binding an event with the **abc div**, but I want to hide the properties div when the **div abc** loses its focus.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can indeed bind the click event and then use the focusout() function inside.

like :

```
(#abc).live('click',function() {

......
(#abc).focusout(function() { .....
});

});
```

If I missed some subtility please tell me ;)

Comment: Did not work :(...
I have added following code inside drop:
$(".textElementClass").live('click', function() {
     $(".textBar").css({'display':'block'});      
     });
     $(".textElementClass").focusout( function() {
         $(".textBar").css({'display':'none'}); 
})

Comment: maybe the droppable protects the click event, try to use dblclick event instead. If it still doesn't work, I'll have a closer look at it.

Comment: Hi Michel,
I added the live out of drop and it worked. The class .textElementClass is actually a paragraph. and I tried to hide properties div using focusout, but it is not working.
At http://api.jquery.com/focusout/, I found it is used with inputs. Does it mean, this will not work with elements other than inputs ?
What is option to do this then?

Comment: I got why it is not working with my elements. focus works only with links and form elements....is there any other way to handle this ?